# Include more close reasons in the flag/cv dialog

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Currently, as I can see the reasons for closing a question as **off-topic** are *only* two:

- **Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with Tezos)
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.
- (Custom comment for people >500 reputation).

I am not very familiar with that topic, but I think that there should be more close-reasons.

So, asking the experts of this site, do you think that there should be more close reasons? If yes, what? Can you answer the question including them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First ask yourself — more close reasons for what? Is there Is there a preponderance of questions which are particularly concerning?

Coming up with more close reasons should not be something you actively seek. Before we start circling up trying to find new ways to rubber stamp questions as unwelcome, it is better to actually *talk* to people in comments about why their question might not fit.

There was a problem in many early communities where it was felt we needed a lot of proactive rules discussions to anticipate problems before they became an issue in actual practice. Generally speaking, we are trying to avoid these hypothetical rules discussions before real examples become more prevalent.

Certainly, if you see a growing class of questions which are *actually* a problem on the site, then feel free to raise a meta support discussion about that specific issue so everyone can have a voice. But there's no need to force a "rules discussion" to brainstorm new ways folks should reject help from this site.

Adding more close reasons has a tendency to do that.